# Books about the Sound Industry_ how it works

Tags: post-production, books, film-industry, job-description, thesis

I'll finish my university in this year and i would write my thesis about Audio Post in Film, compare the industries between my country, other European country and America.

So the very specialised industry compared to a 1 or 2 person team that make the whole soundtrack for a feature film.
I'm looking for some books for this topic like
[image: book]

If the suggestions also contain financial concerns, it would be more than perfect!

Answer (score 2):

The question is a bit vague. There are lots of books about film, and quite a few books about film sound. But most won't mention any differences between Europe/US other than in anecdotal form.

There really is no "magic" difference. The main differences between big "Hollywood blockbuster type" films and typical European films is budget, number of folks working on the film and the scale of things. The scale and size is mainly what drives the other differences such as:
workflow, stricter role divisions, higher specialization in most areas of expertise and of course the possible return of investment that actually drive the main difference ie the budget from the start.

As for books:
Dialog for motion pictures by Purcell.
Anything with or by Walter Murch.
Just search on amazon.
But do read enough different books so that you won't base your paper on just one or two.
Try to avoid technical books from early 90s and earlier. They will give a lot of cool knowledge but they won't explain how we work today technically. Conceptually it's still all the same really :)
The more things change the more they stay the same.

Comment: sorry, your right, its a bit vague.

Comment: i'm interested in, how the big movies who have big budgets work in post sound. how many people, how many different profession exist in one group. of course in Europe, the method howe the people work is quite the same, but in Europe when we have less money than we have to do different parts of the job, they can't pay enough for a bunch of people. i would compare financially this 2 type of working method. i want to prove, if you pay more, or if you give more from the budget, the result could be much better.

Comment: Will a bigger budget make a better film? THAT is a clearer question, and I have a strong personal opinion on that matter.

Comment: yes....Kind of. Its a clear question of course, but the answer is not clear at all. In my country (Hungary) or in this west European region is a bit different in sound.
Normally 1 person will make the whole sound from the field till the mix, and maybe he has some help, but just sometimes. In this region, the directors like this, its much personal, but an Engineer can't be professional in every part. So the golden way is somewhere between this 2 type of method. Germany (as i saw and heard) its like that.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.amazon.ca/Practical-Art-Motion-Picture-Sound/dp/0240812409

This one covers the whole process, and as mentioned Dialogue Editing for Motion Pictures is very practical.

Answer (score 0):

Book like this article?:

http://entertainment.howstuffworks.com/audio-post-production1.htm

any suggestions?